# Time complexity for recursion

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity, recursion, analysis-of-algorithms

For, this recursion, What's the time complexity?

T(n) = 3T(n/2) + O(log n)

I think I can't use the master's theorem because a = 3, b = 2 then log2(3) = 1.58 and f(n) = n^0*log(n), so c = 0 and it doesn't fulfill the 2nd form of the master's theorem where c = logb(a) because 0 != 1.58.

Then if I apply induction and I guess T(n) = O(n) then.

```
T(n) <= 3 * k * n/2 + log (n)
     = 3kn/2 + log(n)
     < kn
```

So T(n) would be O(n). Is that correct?

Comment: It can't be, because $f(n) = n^{(\log 3)/\log 2}$ satisfies exactly $f(n) = 3f(n/2)$. (Note that your calculation incorrectly uses $3kn/2 < kn$.)

Comment: Why f(n) = n^(log3/log2)? Is there an algoithm property that I'm missing?